# Can we continue saying "that" after "resulted in"?

Tags: grammar

I am applying for an Internship for which I am writing a cover letter. I mentioned in it that I had an exit-interview in some other internship. I want to say that the result of that exit-interview was that I exceeded the specifications.

I say it in the following way:

> I had an exit interview to
>   prove my knowledge which resulted in that I have exceeded the program’s specifications.

Is that a correct sentence?

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as a proofreading request, please note that the OP has indicated a specific area of concern in his text, which would make this question **on**-topic.

Comment: 'Which resulted in my exceeding' is how I would put it.'Resulted in that' just sounds altogether wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first phrase, "the result of [which] was that I have exceeded the specifications", is grammatical, although it doesn't really mean what you wanted; your exceeding the specifications wasn't the result of the interview, but of your previous work. "The outcome of which..." or (better) "at which I was told I had exceeded the specifications" would be less ambiguous.

But *resulted in* can only take a noun as object; "resulted in that..." is simply wrong. "Resulted in the fact that I have exceeded the specifications" would be grammatical, though, as mentioned above, it is probably not true. "Resulted in the interviewer telling me that I had exceeded..." is probably the best phrasing.